# Can't update Field A due to unrelated validation error on Field B

Tags: validation, package, managed-package

We provide a managed package on the AppExchange which includes a sync process where we update fields belonging to the managed package, via the BULK API.

Frequently this fails for customers due to validation errors on completely unrelated fields that we don't have control over as they are part of the customers Salesforce setup or other managed packages.

Is it possible to do some kind of partial update that only updates certain fields so that unrelated validation rules do not trigger? Or is it possible to bypass these validation rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now we are working around this issue by asking our customers to set up a dedicated User for the sync process, and to modify their validation rules to allow updates for this User.

Validation rules can be bypassed for a specific User Id by appending a condition like this:

```
&& $User.Id <> '005b0000000XXXX'
```